# Is it proper usage to replace a comma in a list with a semi-colon in this situation (see details)?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, commas

While writing a proposal at work today I needed to mention a list of things and within that list were multi-part items. It seems like replacing the comma with a semi-colon in this situation would make the sentence easier to understand, but is it correct usage?

With standard punctuation this could get confusing:

> Some of my favorite things to do are
>   camping, playing football and
>   baseball, watching Laurel and Hardy
>   Movies, and traveling.

Proposed alternative. Is this acceptable usage?

> Some of my favorite things to do are
>   camping; playing football and
>   baseball; watching Laurel and Hardy
>   Movies; and traveling.

Comment: "With standard punctuation this could get confusing"--in what way? It seems perfectly clear.

Comment: @kajaco I was referring to the nested conjunctions.

Comment: If you had omitted the serial comma, would you be "watching traveling"? Doesn't make much sense in this example, but what if someone thought it was a typo and misunderstood it as Traveling, a film or TV show? Anyway, in your first example, with the serial comma in place, the commas-only sentence is fine. The only commas are the list item separators. If there were extra different types of commas besides those list item separators, then I would use the semicolon, for example if you added nested conjunction lists of more than two items.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Chicago Manual of Style offers these pieces of advice:

> **6.21** *Semicolons within series.* When elements in a series involve
>   internal punctuation, or when they are
>   very long and complex, they should be
>   separated by semicolons.
>
> **6.60** *In a series.* When items in a series involve internal punctuation, they should be separated by semicolons.

.

> Is this acceptable usage?
>
> > Some of my favorite things to do are
> >     camping; playing football and
> >     baseball; watching Laurel and Hardy
> >     Movies; and traveling.

In the specific case of this example sentence, no it isn't, because the semicolon isn't really necessary. Try blowing it up a bit and the semicolon starts to be more useful:

> Some of my favourite things to do are
>   camping with my best friends in isolated,
>   lonely woods; playing football,
>   baseball, eating sausages, offering
>   ridiculous advice on question-and-answer websites;
>   watching Laurel and Hardy, Arnold
>   Schwarznegger, or Sylvester Stallone
>   movies, and travelling to the
>   farthest-flung corners of the globe.

Comment: Should you have added semicolons before each "-ing" word? The semicolons look inconsistent in the example.

Comment: Following up on previous comment: I can imagine playing football and baseball video games on question-and-answer websites, but eating sausages on websites is quite a stretch.

Comment: I agree with jwpat7. In fact, I'd probably punctuate the sentence like this: _Some of my favourite things to do are camping with my best friends in isolated, lonely woods; playing football and baseball; eating sausages; offering ridiculous advice on question-and-answer websites; watching Laurel and Hardy, Arnold Schwarznegger, or Sylvester Stallone movies; and travelling to the farthest-flung corners of the globe._

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't (/one shouldn't) put a semicolon before the final item in the list, beginning 'and'? (Here this is "and travelling to the farthest-flung corners of the globe".)