# Is it "me sitting at a table" or "I sitting at a table"?

Tags: grammaticality, semicolons

The sentence is

> I can recall vivid images of my first atlas; I sitting at a table, finding all countries and their capitals on the atlas, and jotting them down on a paper.

This is the **first** line of a paragraph, and the atlas hasn't been mentioned before this line. I feel that this sentence doesn't sound right, and it seems to have an error after the semi-colon. How can I correct this sentence?

Comment: Try these: "... *me* sitting at ...", or "... atlas: sitting ...".

Comment: indo, I changed the title of the question.  I think this question is interesting and will attract more attention to it, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should read:

> I can recall vivid images of my first atlas; *me,* sitting at a table, finding all countries and their capitals on the atlas, and jotting them down on a paper.

'Me' [is, as per the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115378?rskey=yq9fB2&result=6&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> The objective case of the first person pronoun I, reproducing the Old English accusative and dative.

The important part is sense 5h:

> For the subjective pronoun I. (h: Introducing a sentence or clause with a participle.)

Where the pronoun 'me' introduces the following clause. A relevant example provided is the 1950 one which I have included in the quotation. I'm sure you can see the similarity.

> 1950   J. Hersey Peggety's Parcel of Shortcomings in Fling (1990) 22
>
> "Me, sitting there, taking up half the back seat of the car."

The semicolon here is used either instead of a conjunction, or to link two independent, closely related sentences, and it may make more sense to you if I remove the semicolon and replace it with a conjunction. e.g:

> I can recall vivid images of my first atlas *with me,* sitting at a table, finding all countries and their capitals on the atlas, and jotting them down on a paper.

or,

> I can recall vivid images of my first atlas. *Me,* sitting at a table, finding all countries and their capitals on the atlas, and jotting them down on a paper.

Answer (score 0):

There should be  a 'was' before 'sitting'.
And 'the'  bofore 'atlas' seems right to me, but I cannot support this with an evidence.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> I can recall vivid images of my first atlas. I remember sitting at a table, finding all countries and their capitals in the atlas, and jotting them down on a paper.

(See also [here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57747/any-examples-of-where-a-full-stop-cant-replace-a-semi-colon))