# When is it correct to use a semicolon before a list or quotation (if at all)?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, quotation-marks

Although I don't do it myself, I've noticed many people use a semicolon to introduce a quotation, for instance:

> John said of the event; "it's great to see everyone..."

And the other circumstance: using a semicolon to introduce a list, instead of a colon.

Comment: Related questions: [How does one correctly use a semicolon?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-does-one-correctly-use-a-semicolon) and [Should I use a semicolon or a dash to connect two closely related sentences?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/should-i-use-a-semicolon-or-a-dash-to-connect-two-closely-related-sentences). Please visit the links and see if they answer your question.

Comment: Another one, [Any examples of where a full-stop can't replace a semi-colon?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57747/any-examples-of-where-a-full-stop-cant-replace-a-semi-colon) and there are so many related questions if you use the [search](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=semicolon).

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, the two uses of the semicolon that you've listed are *incorrect*.

Thus:

> INCORRECT: John said of the event; "It's great to see everyone."
>
> CORRECT: John said of the event, "It's great to see everyone."
>
> CORRECT BUT DIFFERENT: John enjoyed the event; "It's great to see everyone," he said.

The last example proves that you *can* have a semicolon immediately before a quotation, but (a) this is rare construction and (b) it's structurally different from the actual example, which is why it works.

---

As for your other instance (using a semicolon to introduce a list, instead of a colon), allow me to invent a sample sentence:

> INCORRECT: I bought three things; apples, bananas, and carrots.
>
> CORRECT: I bought three things: apples, bananas, and carrots.
>
> CORRECT BUT DIFFERENT: I bought three things; apples, bananas, and carrots are all tasty.

The final sentence is structurally different (the words after the semicolon form an independent clause), which is why it works.

---

Note: Since the question was about whether it's ever OK to use a semicolon in place of a colon in these situations, I haven't gone into the details about semicolon use in general or colon use in general, but if you want a refresher, there are great details at the following pages:

*Stack Exchange links:*

- [Semicolon versus dash](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/should-i-use-a-semicolon-or-a-dash-to-connect-two-closely-related-sentences?lq=1)
- [Using a semicolon correctly](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-does-one-correctly-use-a-semicolon?lq=1)
- [Full stop versus semicolon](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57747/any-examples-of-where-a-full-stop-cant-replace-a-semi-colon)

*External links:*

- [Using semicolons (University of Wisconsin Writing Center)](https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html)
- [Semicolons, colons, and dashes (UNC-Chapel Hill Writing Center)](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/semi-colons-colons-and-dashes/)

Answer (score 0):

a ***colon*** is defined as a

> a punctuation mark (:) used to precede a list of items, a quotation, or an expansion or explanation.
>
> • a colon used in various technical and formulaic contexts, for example a statement of proportion between two numbers, or to separate hours from minutes (and minutes from seconds) in a numerical statement of time: 10:1 | 4:30 p.m.

whereas, a ***semicolon*** is defined as a

> a punctuation mark (;) indicating a pause, typically between two main clauses, that is more pronounced than that indicated by a comma.

[Dictionary from OS X]

Generally, a **colon** is used to introduce a list of items, mark the start of a quotation, expansion or explanation, and the various contexts like time.

A **semicolon** is often used to join together two independent clauses — in other words, it joins two clauses that could be sentences.

> Jane drives a Ferrari; John drives a Lamborghini.

Comment: This answer does appear to fit better here [than elsewhere](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291302/colon-vs-semicolon-lydias-father-is-a-master-chef-he-oversees-the-kitchen/291323#291323)