# Should a semicolon be used before a list?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I'm writing a college admissions essay and I have a question regarding the usage of a semicolon.

The sentence is:

> I believe I will thrive in upper division coursework due to traits my family instilled in me; sustained focus, independent initiative, intellectual curiosity, and collaboration.

Is a semicolon the correct punctuation to use after me, or maybe a hyphen, or something else?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it correct to use a semicolon before a list or quotation (if at all)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295251/when-is-it-correct-to-use-a-semicolon-before-a-list-or-quotation-if-at-all)

Comment: Thanks for the response! So it seems that a semicolon wouldn't be correct, and instead it should be a colon?

Comment: Yes, I would use a colon.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)