# Semicolon use before conjunction

Tags: meaning, grammar, punctuation, conjunctions, semicolons

"This is not a film about people with disabilities, but about the deep paths of human communication."

Could I change this to -

"This is not a film about people with disabilities; but the deep paths of human communication."

Or would a comma instead of the semi-colon suffice?

Comment: I'd say a semicolon there is too heavy; a comma is sufficient to mark the boundary of the coordinate.

Comment: I would say a comma isn't even needed here, as the second part is not an independent clause. "This is not a film about people with disabilities**,** but **it is a film about** the deep paths of human communication" would be two independent clauses, using the verb to be in both. I invite you to read this short article : https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/comma/23/comma-before-but/

Comment: Your second clause is not a sentence. No comma is used. If you expect the reader to pause, your best option is an em-dash. Neither of your examples is correct unless your intent for the clause beginning with __but__ is nonessential, which it isn't.

Comment: It's a coordination of two _about_ - preposition phrases. Punctuation does vary, but it's not at all unusual to find a comma being used when the second coordinate asserts an opposite or quite different meaning to the first.

Comment: I see. It's the repetition of "about" that has thrown me slightly..

Comment: _This is not a film [about people with disabilities], but [about the deep paths of human communication]_ . The two bracketed PPs are in coordination; they are modifying the noun "film".

Comment: How would you write this sentence?

Comment: _This is not a film about people with disabilities, but one about the deep paths of human communication_. But that's my personal choice; others may put it another way.

Answer (score 1):

No. A semicolon should be used in one of the following situations:

1. To separate two linked sentences (note: as they are sentences, they must contain a verb)
2. To separate list items that contain commas

In your original sentence, the second part is not a sentence (it contains no verb) and it means nothing standing alone. It does not work to use a semicolon there.

A comma suffices.

For more reading on the list usage of semicolons, see this SE post: [Using a semicolon between elements in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90385/using-a-semicolon-between-elements-in-a-list)

*thanks to @VampDuc for pointing out the need for sentences either side, rather than clauses*

Comment: If I remember correctly, the general rule (to supplement your #1 point) is that both sides of a semicolon should contain complete sentences. Therefore, if either side is not a sentence after adding the semicolon, then you cannot use a semicolon.

Comment: @VampDuc - yes, I think your clarification is correct. Clauses alone are not always sufficient; full sentences are required on both sides. To save confusion, I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: You don't include any supporting evidence for your claims here. And you don't pronounce on whether the second sentence can acceptably start with say 'and' or 'but'.