# Semicolon as a super-comma preceding “etc.”

Tags: semicolons, lists

I was wondering which punctuation to use preceeding **etc.** in an enumeration with semicolons as *supercommas* (as formulated here: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon).

> People with dichromatic colour vision will usually find it difficult to distinguish between similar tones and shades: deep red with black with dark green or dark purple; medium shades of red with similar tones of green and orange; etc.

Should I use a semicolon or a comma before the *etc.*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it proper usage to replace a comma in a list with a semi-colon in this situation (see details)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/is-it-proper-usage-to-replace-a-comma-in-a-list-with-a-semi-colon-in-this-situat)

Comment: There is no mention of the word *etc.* in this other situation so it does not help. *Etc.* is a specific construct within a list, for example always requiring a comma preceeding it (according to Strunk) in a comma-seperated list, even when only preceeded by a single element.

Comment: Thank you, **that** was an answer to my question. I did neither know that *etc.* was immaterial, nor that it would be considered as an element despite its immateriality.

Comment: It is a simple list of 3 elements, not a complex list of 2 elements whose second element contains two subelements. The semicolons makes this much clearer than would the comma.

Comment: Ok, I guess your question is not a perfect duplicate, so I’ve copied my inherently ephemeral comments into an answer with some further illustration/elaboration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple list of 3 elements, not a complex list of 2 elements whose second element contains two subelements.

### Case 1

> 1. deep red with black with dark green or dark purple
> 2. medium shades of red with similar tones of green and orange;
> 3. etc.

### Case 2

> 1. deep red with black with dark green or dark purple
> 2. medium shades of red with similar tones of
>
>    1. green
>    2. orange
>    3. etc.

The semicolons make it clearer that case #1 applies than would the comma.

Contrast:

- People with dichromatic colour vision will usually find it difficult to distinguish between similar tones and shades: **deep red with black with dark green or dark purple; medium shades of red with similar tones of green and orange; etc.**
- People with dichromatic colour vision will usually find it difficult to distinguish between similar tones and shades: **deep red with black with dark green or dark purple, medium shades of red with similar tones of green and orange, etc.**

In the second version, it is far from immediately obvious that we are not talking tones of green, orange, and others.  Using the semicolon makes this clear(er).