# Ages — Semicolons, commas or parentheses?

Tags: punctuation

Which is preferred below--1, 2 or 3? Are all versions technically correct? Which is your pick?

*1. Mike, 25, Jimmy, 44, and Joshua, 49, were arrested on a charge of petit larceny.*

*2. Mike, 25; Jimmy, 44; and Joshua, 49, were arrested on a charge of petit larceny.*

*3. Mike (25), Jimmy (44), and Joshua (49) were arrested on a charge of petit larceny.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it proper usage to replace a coma in a list with a semi-colon?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/is-it-proper-usage-to-replace-a-comma-in-a-list-with-a-semi-colon-in-this-situat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's not likely to be mistaken in this particular example, **#1** makes it difficult to tell whether *Mike* is 25, or if *25* is another item in the list.

**#2** and **#3** are perfectly correct, and very clear.

In this case, I personally prefer **#3**, though, it may not look as clean if you aren't dealing with ages:

> Mike (son), Jimmy (father), Joshua (grandfather), were arrested [...]

In such an event, I would go with the commas and semicolons instead):

> Mike, son; Jimmy, father; Joshua, grandfather; were arrested [...]